# R ggplot: confidence interval plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LmruANHu-qWN8iDuqMvCU3NW_3cxBwM-/view?usp=sharing), and I want to plot confidence interval using `ggplot`'s `stat_summary`.

My code looks like this:

```
file <- read.csv(filepath)
ggplot(file, aes(shop, income, colour = season)) + stat_summary(size = 0.8)
```

[image]

But I want to get something like this:

[image]

So my questions are:

1. How can I change names of "shop" columns?
2. How can I change length of summary lines?
3. How can I set distance between two datalines in one column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach. The size of the bars depends on how intervals are being computed. For the other points you can use `position_dodge()` and `scale_x_discrete()`. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)  
#Code
file <- read.csv('sales.csv')
#Plot
ggplot(file, aes(shop, income, colour = season)) +
  stat_summary(size = 0.8,position = position_dodge(0.25))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Shop â„–1","Shop â„–2"),
                   labels=c('Shop1','Shop2'))
```

Output:

[image]

For y-axis, try this:

```
#Plot 2
ggplot(file, aes(shop, income, colour = season)) +
  stat_summary(size = 0.8,position = position_dodge(0.25))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("Shop â„–1","Shop â„–2"),
                   labels=c('Shop1','Shop2'))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1050,1100,1150))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! Maybe there is a possibility to change scale size to get the result I want?

Comment: @Angelika Yeah, let me add an update, you want specific breaks!

Comment: @Angelika Done lady, I hope that can be helpful for you! Let me know if that worked for you!

Comment: @Angelika Great! Amazing question too!